# How do I use a C# function in a column client template?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-grid

```
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(o => o.TeamName).Title(Site.Resources.Shared.Team);
    columns.Bound(o => o.PersonId).Title(Site.Resources.Shared.Person).ClientTemplate(@Site.CommonFunctions.GetPersonNameById(PersonId));
```

How to pass the PersonId into the C# function to get the return string.I manage to get the return string if hardcoded it like .ClientTemplate(@Site.CommonFunctions.GetPersonNameById(1));

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
.Columns(columns =>
 {
columns.Bound(o => o.TeamName).Title(Site.Resources.Shared.Team);
columns.Bound(o => o.PersonId).Title(Site.Resources.Shared.Person).ClientTemplate(@Site.CommonFunctions.GetPersonNameById("#=PersonId#"));
```

OR

```
.Columns(columns =>
{
columns.Bound(o => o.TeamName).Title(Site.Resources.Shared.Team);
columns.Bound(o => o.PersonId).Title(Site.Resources.Shared.Person).ClientTemplate(@Site.CommonFunctions.GetPersonNameById("+ PersonId +"));
```

Comment: Both of it do not work either...any other suggestion?